# Why aren't Scikit pipelines not reused (from the book Hands-On Machine Learning)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Towards the end of chapter 2 of the book Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow, it builds a set of pipelines to process and prepare the data to train models (page 87 on the 3rd edition and also present in https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb).

The relevant code to my question is this:

```py
def ratio_pipeline():
    return make_pipeline(...)

log_pipeline = make_pipeline(...)

preprocessing = ColumnTransformer([
        ("bedrooms", ratio_pipeline(), ["total_bedrooms", "total_rooms"]),
        ("rooms_per_house", ratio_pipeline(), ["total_rooms", "households"]),
        ("people_per_house", ratio_pipeline(), ["population", "households"]),
        ("log", log_pipeline, ["total_bedrooms", "total_rooms", "population",
                               "households", "median_income"]),
        ...
    ],
    remainder=default_num_pipeline)
```

`ratio_pipeline` is a method that returns a new pipeline each time it's called, while `log_pipeline` is only used once, so it's just created in a (global?) variable.

It does feel like in production code, all pipelines should come from methods, but why does
the book go out of the way to encapsulate `ratio_pipeline` in a method? Can't the same pipeline be used for more than one feature? Would they interfere with each other?